# NullPointerException When trying to call Abstract class - Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, abstract-class

When my submit button is clicked it validates input fields depending on which fields were used, then calls the writeItemToFile() method.

```
private void btnSubmit_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (validateInput()){
        if (enabledFields == "music")
            createMusicItem();
        else
            if (enabledFields == "product")
                createProductItem();}
    writeItemToFile();
}//btnSubmit_actionPerformed
```

The writeItemToFile() method is small and frankly could be skipped, but is needed for my assignment. It calls the write(Item item) method in my Inventory class. It sends along the item declaration at the top of my code.

```
 Item item;
```

The problem is that the Item class is abstract so when it's passed it gives me a NullPointerException. Below is my write(Item item) method just for good measure. My question is this, is there a way I have to instantiate the abstract class? How do I avoid this method.

```
public void write(Item item)
{
    invFilename = item.getFileName();
    File inventoryFile = new File(invFilename);

    try
    {
        invWriter = new FileWriter(inventoryFile, true);
    } // try

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: File " + invFilename + "could not opened: "
                + e.getMessage());
    }//catch

    try
    {
        invWriter.write(item.getFileRecord());
    }//try

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Product " + item.getFileRecord()
                + "could not be written to file " + invFilename + ": "
                + e.getMessage());
    }//catch
}//write(Item item)
```

Please be gentle.

Error message:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Inventory.write(Inventory.java:13)
at AddItemFrame.writeItemToFile(AddItemFrame.java:575)
at AddItemFrame.btnSubmit_actionPerformed(AddItemFrame.java:500)
at AddItemFrame.access$1(AddItemFrame.java:492)
at AddItemFrame$3.actionPerformed(AddItemFrame.java:217)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It being null has nothing to do with it being abstract, it has to do with it being null.

Comment: `== "music"` doesn't feel right.

Comment: please paste your stacktrace

Comment: And in addition to using `==` to compare strings being wrong, it pretty much guarantees no item will be created, hence it'll be null, hence an NPE. You have a path through your code where you'll always try to write a null item. Check it for null, etc.

Comment: the =="music" is because the fields are for a product and for a music file, one's product, one's music. If the music button is clicked the enabledFields string is set to "music".

Comment: @DuncanMcKirdy But that's not how you compare strings in Java.

Comment: Fair point. I changed the == to a .equals statement

Still not working however.

Comment: Use equals method of String class to compare strings not == operator.

Comment: Would be better to see all of the code, but I guess that your method createMusicItem() assigns some value to your item field. If that's right, then you problem should probably be fixed when you replate == with .equals() (as mentioned in comments above)

Comment: Which line is line 13 in your `write(Item item)` method?

Comment: Show all code please, do you have Item item as a class field and you construct it by createMusicItem and createProductItem? If yes, probably there is no item created because of wrong strig comparation. Use equals instead of ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` triggered by your `write` method is likely to be caused by a `null` argument of type `Item`, specifically on:

`item.getFileName();` --> invoking method of `null` `Object`.

It could also be caused by:

`new File(invFilename)` --> initializing new `File` with `null` argument (if `item` is not `null`, but `item.getFileName()` is).

... etc.

Nothing to do with the fact that `Item` is an abstract class.

**Note**

As mentioned by others in the comments, `String` contents comparison is done by `equals`, not the `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

> the Item class is abstract

That means you cannot have an object of this class. You need to extend the abstract class and pass an object of your new class.

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) : *Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed*

Comment: You can have a reference of type `Item` though and that reference can be `null`, passed as an argument, etc

Comment: Sure but the question is "is there a way I have to instantiate the abstract class?"

Comment: @LyK Yes, but the question asker seems to be asking the wrong question, based on his best guess. You're answering the "question" but not providing a solution.

Comment: Probably this is true, yes... However, the notion in SO is to provide answers to the questions, which in turn need to be the correct ones. I am not sure whether he understands the fact regarding the abstract class. (and he probably wants/needs to create an object that extends Item). I see your point though

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is that the Item class is abstract so when it's passed it gives me a NullPointerException."

Abstract does not mean `null`. An abstract class cannot be *directly instantiated*, but its sub-classes may. Therefore it is perfectly legal to have a function such as

```
public String getAbstrClassesToString(AnAbstractClass abstract_class)  {
   try  {
      return  abstract_class.toString();
   }  catch(NullPointerException npx)  {
      if(abstract_class == null)  {
         throw  new NullPointerException("abstract_class");
      }

      //Just in case the toString() throws an NPX
      throw  npx;
   }
}
```

Now you *could* call this with

```
getAbstrClassesToString(null);
```

which will obviously result in a `NullPointerException`, ***or*** you could call this with

```
getAbstrClassesToString(new ConcreteSubClassOfAnAbstractClass());
```

which is perfectly legal, and obviously *not* null.

In other words, your `NullPointerException` problem is unrelated to abstract-ness.

More information: https://www.google.com/search?q=abstract+class+java+tutorials

Answer (score -5):

The object of type `Item` that is being passed must be instantiated.

As pointed out by others, you cannot simply create it via:

```
Item item = new Item(); // this does not work!
```

However, you can `extend` the class and create all the abstract methopds required and then instantiate the new class.

```
class ItemB extends Item
{
  ...
}
```

Then you can work with the new class,

```
ItemB item = new ItemB();
```

Comment: "the Item class is abstract" he said you cant use a "constructor" there

Comment: If it's abstract, you can't instantiate it.

Comment: even if this were helpful, this is a comment at best